# Is it possible to edit function definition box info with Coc + Vim?

Tags: plugin-coc, ide

When I am writing php code, I often create a comment before a function. This comment also includes the comments for a parameter. Like this:

```
/**
* This function finds cheese.
* @param $mix is the number of cheese variants
*
*/
function findCheese($mix) {
   // do stuff cheese related
}
```

However, when I use coc-hover (which brings up the function definition), it shows me my comments AND automatically added param comments which just say `mixed @param`. I want to remove all these generic definitions from the popup function definition.

I do not believe this is a bug. But I cannot find anything, anywhere on where vim draws this information from and how to change the contents of the popup box.

Note: `"inlayHint.enable": false` doesn't accomplish this for me.

Answer (score 1):

After playing with some more, I have discovered that you can achieve this by adding the variable type after `@param`.

For example:

```
/**
* This function finds cheese.
* @param string $mix is the number of cheese variants
*
*/
```

Notice i added `string` after @param.

Now, the definition box only has my defined info